# How to make ajax load more content, using button pagination work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I intend to load more videos into a div/page using load more button pagination with ajax, xhr status shows status as ok(200) but no video content is loaded.

`videos.php`:

```
<div id="videosline " class="col-md-3 content-grid ">

<?php //code to get first 3 videos working   ?>
</div>
<button id="loadvideos" class="btn ">Load More</button>
```

//ajax jquery code to load in more three videos at every button click

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var videoscount = 3;
$("#loadvideos").click(function(){
    videoscount = videoscount + 3;
$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url:"loadmore.php",
     data:{

        'videosnewcount':videoscount
     },
     sucess: function(data){
        $('videosline').append(data);
     }

});
```

`loadmore.php`:

```
    <?php
       include 'master.php';//some php config and db config
       $videosnewcount = 3;
        $condition =  [];

        array_push($condition,['mediatype = ' => ['video/mp4','AND']]);



        $data = find('files',$condition,["ORDER BY " => "id DESC","LIMIT" => $videosnewcount ]); //php function for mysql query


        foreach($data as $video) { ?>

    <?php if($video['mediatype'] == 'video/mp4') { ?>


                <?php include('cards/video.php'); ?>



            } 
        }
        ?>
```

`cards/video.php`:

```
<?php if(explode('/',$video['mediatype'])[0] == 'video') { ?>
    <a href="mediafile.php?id=<?= $video['id']?>&medianame=<?= $video['filename']?>"><div style=" height:;">
<video  controlslist="nodownload"  oncontextmenu="return false;" poster="member/<?= $video['poster'] ?>" style="height:250px; width:100%; " type="video/mp4" class="pr100"  src="member/<?= $video['path'] ?>" > </video</div></a><?php } ?>
```

Comment: sucess: function(data){
        $('#videosline').append(data);
     } 
videosline  is id of div.

Comment: Using just `LIMIT` with 1 number will not do pagination

Comment: Whats the response of the ajax call?

Comment: okay, yeah that is also a mistake but  just fixed that still didnt work.

Comment: the response is 200 in the console

Comment: `200` is the response code, telling you that the request was fulfilled. Can you show us the response *data* from the request? In Chrome, press Ctrl+Shift+I to open DevTools. Click on the "Network" tab and locate the request to `loadmore.php`. Click on the request and then on the tab "Response". There's the response data of the request.

Comment: Can you share the full URL to `loadmore.php`?.

Comment: Minor format fixes

Comment: @RawlandHustle what i see is XHR tab under network and the status there says 200

Comment: I am working on my localhost. not online

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it matters but in `loadmore.php`, you are not getting the GET parameter from the Ajax call so I don't know why you are sending it.

What do matters, is that `loadmore.php` is not echoing any data so your Ajax response should be empty. Also, I can't see that your sending any query to your database. Where is the "SELECT from table WHERE..."?

Comment: am sending the get parameter to which has the number of videos to be outputted(limit) by the loadmore.php . Also am using a php function called find() which i created in master.php to run select * from query.

Comment: when i go to the url loadmore.php it works fine, more using ajax to call it into videos,php isnt working and thats the problem

Comment: You're sending the parameter `videosnewcount` to `loadmore.php` but `loadmore.php` is not using it. Instead you have set the PHP variable `$videosnewcount` to always be 3: `$videosnewcount = 3;`.

Comment: if (isset($_GET['videosnewcount'])) { }

i have corrected that

Comment: i think my problem now is that am using ajax here as though it is returning a text as response not a video as response.